# Почему "return" не возвращает значение?

Tags: javascript

```
cell(numX, numY) {
  this.cells.map((cell) => {
    if (numX == cell.opts.numX && numY == cell.opts.numY) {
      console.log(cell);
      return cell;
    }
  });
}
```

Код выше определенно находит необходимый Cell (так как console.log() выводит то, что необходимо). Но вот `return` это значение не возвращает. Для меня остается непонятным, почему код ниже работает как надо, а этот код работать не хочет. **Прошу объяснить**.

```
cell(numX, numY) {
    let xcell;
    this.cells.map((cell) => {
      if (numX == cell.opts.numX && numY == cell.opts.numY) {
        console.log(cell);
        xcell = cell;
        return;
      }
      return;
    });
    return xcell;
  }
```

Кстати, хотелось бы добавить. Мне необходимо, чтобы, когда нужный элемент найден, он тут же возвращался бы, не заставляя цикл доходить до конца (заведомо известно, что найден может быть только один элемент). Тут дело в том, что поиск будет производится по довольно большому количеству элементов, и лишние проверки тут ни к чему. Поэтому как только элемент найден - нужно его сразу вернуть. А Debug-Console в Chrome показывает мне, что даже после того, как элемент найден и return сработал, цикл продолжает выполняться в поисках других элементов, что в корне неверно, ведь return должен не только вернуть значение, но и прекратить выполнение блока, в котором он находится (насколько мне известно).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы используете метод `map`, который возвращает *новый массив*, где каждый элемент является результатом вызова функции, которую вы передает в качестве параметра

На простом примере

```
const nums = [1, 2, 3, 4]
const doubleNums = nums.map( n => n * 2 )
// doubleNums= [2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Что происходит в этом коде: мы передаем `map` функцию `n => n * 2`, это значит, что мы пройдет по нашему массиву циклом, умножим каждый элемент массива на 2 и из результатов создадим новый массив, который будет записан в переменную `doubleNums`

Поэтому ваш код работает не так как вы ожидаете, он не вернет вам нужную ячейку, а просто вызовет функцию для каждого элемента вашего массива.

```
cell(numX, numY) {
  this.cells.map((cell) => {
    if (numX == cell.opts.numX && numY == cell.opts.numY) {
      console.log(cell);
      return cell;
    }
  });
}
```

В вашем случае лучше использовать метод `filter`, который так же вызывает функцию для каждого элемента, но в новом массиве будут только те элементы, при которых функция, которую мы передали как аргумент в `filter`, вернула `true`

На простом примере

```
const nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const numsLessThan3 = nums.filter( n => n < 3 );
// numsLessThan3 = [1, 2];
```

На вашем примере

```
cell(numX, numY) {
  return this.cells.filter((cell) =>
      numX == cell.opts.numX &&
      numY == cell.opts.numY
  )[0]; 
  // [0], так как нам нужен только первый элемент,
  // подразумевается что он всегда будет один
}
```

**UPDATE**

Если хотите оптимизировать кода, то тогда воспользуйтесь циклом

```
cell(numX, numY) {
  let neededCell = null
  const {length} = this.cells
  for(let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      const cell = this.cells[i]
      if (numX == cell.opts.numX && numY == cell.opts.numY) {
          neededCell = cell
          break // выйдет из цикла
          // либо можно сразу return cell
          // без break и neededCell = cell
      }
  }
  return neededCell
}
```

Comment: Я немного обновил вопрос. Мне заведомо известно, что результатом будет только один элемент, а filter, насколько я понимаю, пройдется по всем элементам даже после того, как нужный будет найден. Поэтому filter мне не совсем подходит, если я правильно понимаю его суть. Но, так как вопрос стоял в "объяснить, почему", то вы абсолютно точно заслуживаете "решения". Но если еще и предложите вариант получше filter, то буду очень благодарен.

Comment: Все, пока писал, вы обновили уже. Благодарю :)

Comment: @smellyshovel, если нужно найти _один_ элемент, то можно использовать [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: @Grundy это подходит, спасибо :) А можете объяснить, почему в ES2015 это стандарт, а в ES2017 написано, что черновик? Это типа поддержку убрать хотят, или как?

Comment: @smellyshovel, потому что ES2015 стандарт уже готов, а ES2017 стандарт - только разрабатывается. В колонке Статус показывается состояние _спецификации_.

Comment: @Grundy ааа... Тогда ясно, спасибо